# Problem With Saving Pandas Dataframe to sqlite database, Unsupported Datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
          lists
    0  [1, 2, 3, 4]
    1        [1, 3]
```

I'm trying to put it in to the database, according to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False) 
df.to_sql('name1', con=engine)
```

After that I got huge stacktrace, with the most meaningful:

```
(sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO nam2 ("index", lists) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ((0, [1, 2, 3, 4]), (1, [1, 3]))]
```

Means Python's list seems to be not supported as a value. The question is, is there a way to put pandas or Python (I will optimize it anyway) list into the database? feather also refused working with lists; I will need store huge postings on a hard drive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are generally not supported by most relational databases.  Python lists in particular would be a nightmare because they can contain any object.  A few relational databases support arrays since they are difficult to query against and eat up storage space.

However, you need to rethink how you are storing your data.  If you need to store nested structures, you should consider using a noSQL database.  If you just have flat lists, you can break those into independent tables for storage.

Comment: There's gonna be postings, means lots of flat lists of integers, will try to redesign in that way, will see.